# How to overwrite the SLDC css class class in LWC?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

Is it possible to overwrite the SLDC css classes?

I tried changing below :

```
.slds-input:focus, .slds-input:active{
    border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0) !important;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

I wanted to change the border-color to red, but it eventually defaults to blue on the component. `rgb(21, 137, 238);`

Is there a way to change the border-color property of the css class?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Thanks.. that makes sense. So, there is no way of changing the default style value of the child components? there must be some way out for this?

Comment: you can't using the namespaced components, as I had mentioned in a comment in one of your previous posts. you will have to create your own, and you can still leverage slds while doing so, its just a bit more work.